# Min max алгоритм или как сделать ползунок сложности в игре?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Я написал небольшую игру на js (крестики нолики), где по очереди ходит игрок и компьютер. Компьютер высчитывает ходы и ходит по алгоритму minmax, то есть просчитывая ходы наперед.

Как мне реализовать уровни сложности, как регулировать сложность этого алгоритма? В голову приходит только ограничение глубины рекурсии, дабы ограничить количество просчитанных ходов наперед. Возможно есть более подходящие алгоритмы?

Comment: Или добавить рандома при определенном количестве шагов. Например, на легком пока текущее количество заполненных ячеек меньше 6 - компьютер рандомно ходит. На сложном это же условие для 3 ячеек